# Choose install location on Debian installation

Tags: partitioning, debian, installation

Noob here

I'd just like to know if I can choose where to install Debian during the installation.

Because I'll use a valid PC to boot up the installer to install on a HDD of an old PC that cannot manage to boot a USB. And I don't want Debian to take over my working computer !

Thanks,
Silloky

Comment: Yes you can. Can you make a mistake? Yes you can too. You should make a backup first if you don't feel confident.

Comment: @A.B Great ! Thanks!